Sequelize bulkCreate() default value without id
I have the following model
interface UserSalary
  extends Model<InferAttributes<UserSalary>, InferCreationAttributes<UserSalary>> {
  user_id: number;
  salary_id: number;
}

const UserSalary= webSide?.define<UserSalary>(
  "user_salary",
  {
   
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    s_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  { tableName: "user_salary", timestamps: false }
);

export default UserSalary;


and i have
let userSalaryList= [{ user_id: 1 ,salary_id: 1},{ user_id: 2 ,salary_id:4},{ user_id: 3 ,salary_id: 6}]

i want to use bulkCreate to push userSalaryList  :
await UserRole?.bulkCreate(userSalaryList, {
    transaction: transaction
  });

but i get the following error
original: error: Column "id" of relation "user_role" does not exist

i dont have id in the database tabel
can someone helpe me

Are UserSalary and UserRole the same model? Why do you try to pass UserSalary objects to UserRole method?
